# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it error in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Subline database.conf file:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'), 
'connections' => [ 'sqlite' => 
                             [ 'driver' => 'sqlite', 
                             'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')), 
                            'prefix' => '', ],  

'mysql' => [ 'driver' => 'mysql', 
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost').('homstead'==gethostname()?null:':33060'), 
'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'localhost:3306'), 
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homstead'), 
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homstead'), 
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'), 
'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 
'prefix' => '', 
'strict' => false, 
'engine' => null, ],
```

command prompt error:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to give more details on your problem ?

Comment: And it would be better to copy your code and the errors and paste them here.

Comment: here is code of database.config file

Comment: 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

Comment: 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost').('homstead'==gethostname()?null:':33060'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'localhost:3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homstead'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homstead'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

Comment: here is a command that i run on windows cmd.exe

Comment: Your  'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost').('homstead'==gethostname()?null:':33060'), doesn't make sense. It should be just 'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'), and make sure you have the right server information in your .env file

Comment: previously the settings was 'host; => env('DB_HOST','localhost'), but its not working !!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are having multiple ports in the connection, you only need to have it under the `port` key

```
'default'       => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'connections'   => [
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => ''
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homstead'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homstead'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
]
```

Also removed the concatenated host string